# Divide the columns in mysql into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am completely new to mysql. Here I am trying to make a query in `mysql` which divides a column `col1` into 4 different columns based on its category(`col2`) in sorted order as shown below. I have written a query like this till now:

```
select if(category = 'first',name ,NULL) as first,
if(category = 'second',name,NULL) as second,
if(category = 'third',name,NULL) as third,
if(category = 'fourth',name,NULL) as fourth
from 'table';
```

this code gives me the four columns but I am stuck now as I am not able to further filter this.

Given table:

```
name     category
John     first
Sunil    third
Jenny    third
Ashley   fourth
Meera    second
Abhay    first
```

Required answer:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
Abhay   Meera   Jenny   Ashley
John    NULL    Sunil   NULL
```

Note that all the columns in the answer are sorted.

> Edit: I guess the question is not clear about the format of final answer. Thanks @philipxy for pointing out. Final answer should be adjusted in least number of rows (which is 2 in my case). All the columns should have equal number of rows and if some column has lesser values then that row will have `NULL` value in respective columns e.g `col2` and `col 4` above. Finally all the columns should be in sorted order where `NULL` will be in the last(if any)e.g Suppose there was an entry named `Olly` with `category` `fourth` then it should appear before `NULL` in `col4` and after `Ashley`.

Comment: is required output suppose to have only 2 rows ? or could there be more depending on the number of rows in the original table ?

Comment: There can be more rows. I have shown here just an example.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? This is forcing values into the rows of a table as if it were a gui grid. You should likely not be formatting in an sql table, you should be formatting in a gui. Considering that you don't know what "select t.*" means. you are almost certainly don't want the result you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky.  You are trying to stack lists vertically, rather than horizontally, which is not a "normal" SQL operation.

You can do what you want by using conditional aggregation.  The problem is there is nothing to aggregate by.  The solution is to introduce a variable column to calculate a sequence number for aggregation:

```
select max(case when category = 'first' then name end) as first,
       max(case when category = 'second' then name end) as second,
       max(case when category = 'third' then name end) as third,
       max(case when category = 'fourth' then name end) as fourth
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = category, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := category, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from `table` t cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by category
     ) t
group by rn;
```

If you want the values in a particular order in each column, then add a second sort key after `category`.

EDIT:

I should note that if you don't need multiple rows, but just the values, you can concatenate them together:

```
select group_concat(case when category = 'first' then name end) as firsts,
       group_concat(case when category = 'second' then name end) as seconds,
       group_concat(case when category = 'third' then name end) as thirds,
       group_concat(case when category = 'fourth' then name end) as fourths
from`table` t
group by rn;
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the logics for which  the variables are used in your code and also  I don't  understand this part: `select t.*` What is `t.*`?

Comment: @SunilKumar . .  `t` is a table alias.  You learn about user defined variables in the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).  Run the subquery by itself if you want to see how they work for this query.

Comment: Please give a reference to MySQL (or *any* SQL DBMS) specs that defines assignment to a variable in a SELECT with a FROM as executing a variable assignment for every row, in ORDER BY order, with subselects before containing expressions? Your claim that this answer is a solution to the question relies it, but although there are some cryptic suggestive phrases in the linked documentation, this semantics is not documented anywhere.

Comment: @philipxy . . . The subquery defines `rn`.